# Validación de usuarios registrados

Tags: php, mysql

Buen dia,

Pueden ayudarme por favor, deseo que cuando la persona exista en la base de datos no se registre y esta redireccione automáticamente a otra pagina, pero no me funciona, esta siempre me ingresa la información a la base de datos aun si esta duplicada.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Registration</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css" />
</head>
<body>

<?php
                  require('db.php');
                    // If form submitted, insert values into the database.


               if (isset($_REQUEST['username'])){
                            // removes backslashes
                   $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']);
                            //escapes special characters in a string
                    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username); 

                    $email = stripslashes($_REQUEST['email']);
                    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$email);

                    $telefono = stripslashes($_REQUEST['telefono']);
                    $telefono = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$telefono);

                    $empresa = stripslashes($_REQUEST['empresa']);
                    $empresa = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$empresa);

                    $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
                    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);

                    $trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

// validacion de usuario registrado

            include 'db.php';

                $buscarUsuario = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$_POST[email]' ";
                $result = $con ->query($buscarUsuario);
                $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if($count == 1) {header("Location: registration_duplicated.php");}

                else{

                      $query = "INSERT into `users` (username, password, email, telefono, empresa, trn_date)
                                        VALUES ('$username', '".md5($password)."', '$email', '$telefono','$empresa', '$trn_date')";

                       $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

                     if($result){header("Location: Registro_exitoso.php");}

                        }}

                        else{
                    ?>

    <div class="wrapper fadeInDown1">
    <div id="formContent">

                <a href="login.php"><h2 class="inactive underlineHover"> Ingresar </h2></a>
                <h2 class="active"> Registrarte </h2>


                        <form name="registration" action="" method="post">


                            <input type="text" class="fadeIn regitration" name="username" placeholder="Usuario" required />

                            <input type="email"  class="fadeIn regitration" name="email" placeholder="Correo" required />

                            <input type="password" class="fadeIn regitration" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required />

                            <input type="tel" class="fadeIn regitration" name="telefono" placeholder="Telefono" required />

                            <input type="text" class="fadeIn regitration" name="empresa" placeholder="Empresa" required />

                            <input type="submit" class="fadeIn regitration" name="submit" value="Registrarse" />

                        </form>


    </div>
    </div>


<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cambia esta linea asi: `$buscarUsuario = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' ";`

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! fijate en tu codigo utilizas el email de dos formas distintas.. en uno lo buscas como $_POST[email] y en el otro lado directamente como $email. puede estar ahi el problema?

Comment: @alanfcm Muchas Gracias, Sin embargo aun me los sigue insertando en la base de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te voy a sugeir que lo hagas de esta forma si gustas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
                      require('db.php');
                        // If form submitted, insert values into the database.


                   if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                                // removes backslashes
                       $username = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
                                //escapes special characters in a string
                        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username); 

                        $email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
                        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$email);

                        $telefono = stripslashes($_POST['telefono']);
                        $telefono = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$telefono);

                        $empresa = stripslashes($_POST['empresa']);
                        $empresa = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$empresa);

                        $password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
                        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);

                        $trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    // validacion de usuario registrado

                include 'db.php';

                    $buscarUsuario = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' ";
                    $result = $con ->query($buscarUsuario);
                    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                if($count > 0) {

                      header("Location: registration_duplicated.php");

                    }else{

                          $query = "INSERT into `users` (username, password, email, telefono, empresa, trn_date)
                                            VALUES ('$username', '".md5($password)."', '$email', '$telefono','$empresa', '$trn_date')";

                           $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

                         if($result){
                       header("Location: Registro_exitoso.php");

                           } else{

                         echo"hubo un error.mysqli_error($con)";


                        }
                    } 
                        ?>

        <div class="wrapper fadeInDown1">
        <div id="formContent">

                    <a href="login.php"><h2 class="inactive underlineHover"> Ingresar </h2></a>
                    <h2 class="active"> Registrarte </h2>


                            <form name="registration" action="" method="post">


                                <input type="text" class="fadeIn regitration" name="username" placeholder="Usuario" required />

                                <input type="email"  class="fadeIn regitration" name="email" placeholder="Correo" required />

                                <input type="password" class="fadeIn regitration" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required />

                                <input type="tel" class="fadeIn regitration" name="telefono" placeholder="Telefono" required />

                                <input type="text" class="fadeIn regitration" name="empresa" placeholder="Empresa" required />

                                <input type="submit" class="fadeIn regitration" name="submit" value="Registrarse" />

                            </form>


        </div>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, use tu **if($count > 0)** sobre mi script original y me funciono.

Comment: vale que bueno que te sirvio saludos y exitos!!

Answer (score 0):

```
//Te dejo un ejemplo como podrias solucionar tu problema
```

$sql="SELECT * FROM tu_tabla WHERE email='correo@ejemplo.com'"; //la consulta sql
$db->prepare($sql)->execute(); //ejecuta la consulta
 
$resultado=$db->fetchAll(); //recupera los datos
if($resultado){
        header("location:inicio.php");
}
else{
        //en  este caso se registra a la base de datos
}

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, revisa [answer] para realizar buenas respuestas, saludos.